# Is there a consolidated way of writing several prototype functions for a single object?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have about eight prototype functions for the Date object. I would like to avoid repeating `Date.prototype`. Is there a consolidated way of writing several prototype functions for a single object?

I tried this to no avail:

```
Date.prototype = {
  getMonthText: function(date){
    var month = this.getMonth();
    if(month==12) month = 0;
    return ['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC'][month];
  },
  getDaysInMonth: function(date){
    return 32 - new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 32).getDate();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing, you are replace the prototype with your new object.

If you use jQuery, it has a $.extend method that you could use like `$.extend(Date.prototype, { getMonthText: function(date){...},  getDaysInMonth: function(date){...} })`

If you dont use, you could easily create an extend like function with:

```
function extend(proto,newFunctions) {
   for (var key in newFunctions)
       proto[key] = newFunctions[key]
}
```

And call with:

```
extend(Date.prototype,{ getMonthText: function(date){...},  getDaysInMonth: function(date){...} });
```

Another way is just do it directly:

```
Date.prototype.getDaysInMonth = function(date){ ... }
Date.prototype.getMonthText = function(date){ ... }
```

I'd argue that this is more readable than the extend function.

Comment: I assume this is less efficient during run time. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, using an extend function should be less efficient, but it will only run once and the time is negligible. As people say "premature optimization is the root of all evil". You may just pick which one looks more readable for you.

Comment: I agree with you, the Date.prototype.x = function() is more readable.

Comment: FWIW, Prototype implements an `Object.extend()` method that works in much the same way.